# What API Objects work with the InvokeExecute() AMPScript function?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api

The only example provided in the official documentation for the [**InvokeExecute()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/invokecreate.htm) AMPScript function is for logging an unsubscribe event.  I've only ever seen it used for that purpose.

Do any of you know what other objects work with the `InvokeExecute()` function?

There aren't any hints that I can find in the [**SOAP API method overview**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.htm) or the [**Execute Method**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/execute.htm).

Comment: The only two uses I have found is Refresh Group (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/refreshing_a_group.htm) and Unsub Event as you stated.  I feel like this method is that mysterious stranger, who no one knows who he is or what he does, but everyone respects him.